# how to read xml file in xquery

Tags: xml, xquery, osb

I am trying to read an xml file using XQuery.
    On trying a lot in google what all I found relevant is doc() function. But it is not working for me.
    I have kept my xml file and Xquery under same folder in eclipse. But Xquery is giving error: line 13, column 6: {err}XP0004: Invalid static type: untypedDocument?

```
My Xquery:


     declare function xf:LookupXML($dvm1 as element(ns0:dvm),
        $DVMName as element(*),
        $SourceColumn as element(*))
        as element(*) {
             doc('CityCode.xml')     
    };

    declare variable $dvm1 as element(ns0:dvm) external;
    declare variable $DVMName as element(*) external;
    declare variable $SourceColumn as element(*) external;

    xf:LookupXML($dvm1,
        $DVMName,
        $SourceColumn)

My xml file:- Name- CityCode.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:dvm name="" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/SuburbCode" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/SuburbCode SuburbCode.xsd ">
  <tns:columns>
    <tns:column name="City"/>
    <tns:column name="Code"/>
  </tns:columns>
  <tns:rows>
    <tns:row>
      <tns:cell>Mumbai</tns:cell>
      <tns:cell>BOM</tns:cell>
    </tns:row>
     <tns:row>
      <tns:cell>Delhi</tns:cell>
      <tns:cell>DLH</tns:cell>
    </tns:row>
     <tns:row>
      <tns:cell>Banglore</tns:cell>
      <tns:cell>BLR</tns:cell>
    </tns:row>
  </tns:rows>
</tns:dvm>


If anyone knows please provide solution.
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare your function to return an element node, but it returns a document node (the function `doc()` returns a document node, which in turn is the return sequence for your function).

From the error message, it seems the query is not even evaluated, it fails compilation, because the static analysis tells the compiler that can never succeed.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you can either say your function return a document node (using `as document-node()`) instead of an element, or to return the root element from the document by using the following:

```
doc('CityCode.xml')/*
```

Comment: Just out of interest, do you know which XQuery processor you are using?

Comment: Please paste your adapted example and complete error message.

Comment: It just occurred to me that it might be about one of the external variable, declared as element nodes.  If you change the type to `as document-node() external`, you might find that you initialize one of them to a document node instead of an element, as declared.  But you did not show how you bind those external variables in you processor.